# How to free Google App Engine and datastore cache using GWT Application on Localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, browser

When I run the application the browser caches the Application even If I do changes on the interface
it doesn't do anything just the same application appears every time also it caches the data I stored on datastore 
I assumed that it's a browser cache problem 
so how actually to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched again and found the problem 
you have to remove this line from **appengine-web.xml**\

```
<include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
```

Re-run your project and the browser won't cache anymore 
Problem Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear it manually, not by programming. there is a solution for chrome.
Just enter chrome://appcache-internals/ in the url, there you can clear your browser cache manually.